# Eclipse - Print report from app with Google Cloud Print

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin, pdf-generation, itext, google-cloud-print

I am developing an android application in eclipse to print a report via Google Cloud Print.
This [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/android) from Google has me on the right track. 
I have already installed [itext](http://itextpdf.com/download.php) to generate the Report.pdf

My problem is in the "print" element of my applications UI. Google supplies this code:

```
Intent printIntent = new Intent(this, PrintDialogActivity.class);
printIntent.setDataAndType(docUri, docMimeType);
printIntent.putExtra("title", docTitle);
startActivity(printIntent);
```

With the message:

> "In the code above, replace the three parameters as follows: docUri -
>   URI of the document to be printed docMimeType - MIME type of the
>   document to be printed. We recommend that you use PDF
>   (application/pdf) format docTitle - title of the printed document,
>   arbitrary string that will be shown on the GCP management console as
>   the print job's title

My PDF is saved at `/data/Student/StudentReportPDF.pdf`

I have tried changing the docUri, docMimeType and docTitle has follows: With no luck

```
Intent printIntent = new Intent(this, PrintDialogActivity.class);
printIntent.setDataAndType(StudentReportPDF, .pdf);
printIntent.putExtra("title", Student Report);
startActivity(printIntent);
```

All 3 elements result in red squigglies.

Can someone spot my mistake or I guess clarify these 3 elements for me?

printing eclipse-plugin pdf-generation itext google-cloud-print

Comment: Just checking, you do have .pdf in quotes right?

Comment: @UPGRAYEDD did you able to print the report, i am also using cloud print.., but my printer is not there in Printers list. what might be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Big thanks to DragonRancher via Reddit

dragonrancher 1 point 1 hour ago
When using the Java language, you need to put your strings between double quotes, otherwise they are interpreted as identifiers.
Your putExtra line should probably look like:

```
printIntent.putExtra("title", "Student Report");
```

The setDataAndType line has other issues though. According to the documentation, the setDataAndType method requires a Uri object and a string containing a MIME type. In this case, you might be able to use the Uri.fromFile or Uri.parse methods to get a Uri object from your filename, and the MIME type for PDFs is application/pdf:

```
printIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File("Report.pdf")), "application.pdf");
```

I don't actually have any experience with Android, so someone else might be able to better comment on determining the path for your report file.